# For a multiclassed Ancestral Guardians barbarian/Echo Knight fighter, how do the Ancestral Protectors and Manifest Echo features interact?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, fighter, barbarian, echo-knight

Let's say I have three levels in Barbarian and three in Fighter.

As a barbarian, I choose the [Path of the Ancestral Guardian](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#PathoftheAncestralGuardian) subclass, so I gain the [Ancestral Protectors](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#AncestralProtectors-636) feature (XGtE, p. 10):

> While you’re raging, the first creature you hit with an attack on your turn becomes the target of the warriors, which hinder its attacks. Until the start of your next turn, that target has disadvantage on any attack roll that isn't against you, and when the target hits a creature other than you with an attack, that creature has resistance to the damage of the target’s attacks.

I also choose to be an [Echo Knight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#EchoKnight) as my Fighter subclass. The second bullet of the [Manifest Echo](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#ManifestEcho-1810360) feature says (EGtW, p. 183):

> When you take the Attack action on your turn, any attack you make with that action can originate from your space or the echo's space. You make this choice for each attack.

How do the Ancestral Protectors and Manifest Echo features interact?

If my first attack originates from the echo's space (i.e. the echo attacks), would the Ancestral Protectors encourage the enemy to attack the echo (i.e. by hindering attacks against targets other than the echo), or to attack my character (as normal for Ancestral Protectors)?

If it encourages the enemy to attack the echo, does the effect remain even after it is dispersed, so the baddy still attacks other targets with disadvantage?

Or does it just encourage the enemy to attack me, as usual? (In that case, I can basically use the echo to make me a super-annoying ranged tank that forces enemies to choose between trying to chase me down, and attacking a target other than me with both disadvantage on the attack and resistance to the damage for the target.)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### *You* are making the attack from the echo's space.

This is spelled out in the feature description of Manifest Echo:

> When you take the Attack action on your turn, any attack *you make* with that action can originate from your space or the echo's space.

The Manifest Echo feature does not say your echo makes the attack, rather it changes the space *your* attack originates from.

Then, by Ancestral Guardians, the target has disadvantage on all attack rolls that aren't against you, since you made the attack.

Notably, your echo *is not a creature*, so Ancestral Guardians would not give your echo resistance to damage from attacks made against your echo (which is usually going to be entirely trivial as your echo has 1 hp).

#### A point of clarification.

To clarify, *Ancestral Protectors doesn't compel the target to attack you*. It only gives them disadvantage on attack rolls unless they are attacking you.

Comment: Thanks! Then I'll just use it as a way to harry enemies that tried to just move around me. Or just mess with the big baddie while a more armored tank holds it down!